# Displaying lat lng wherever user clicks

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web

I want to display latitude and longitude a location that user clicks on the map wherever they wants (I'm not using marker event), but it still  shows. Here is my code:

```
 var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

    function initialize()
    {
    var mapProp = {
      center:myCenter,
      zoom:5,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
      position:myCenter,
      });

    marker.setMap(map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) 
    {
    infowindow.setContent(event.LatLng.lat()+","+event.latlng.lng());
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
      });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `position`-property of the marker as well in the `click`-handler:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) 
{
  marker.setPosition(event.latLng);  
  infowindow.setContent(event.latLng.lat()+","+event.latLng.lng());
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Note: it must be exactly `latLng` and not `LatLng` or `latlng`

Demo:

```js
    function initialize() {
      var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);
      var mapProp = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
      });

      marker.setMap(map);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infowindow.setContent(event.latLng.lat() + "," + event.latLng.lng());
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      
      google.maps.event.trigger(map,'click',{latLng:map.getCenter()})
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```

Comment: when you click on "run code snippet" above it didn't work?

Comment: oohh yeah it works. this is what i want. thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this will show the you how to get the longitude and latitude whenever the user clicks the map.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function( event ){
      alert( "Latitude: "+event.latLng.lat()+" "+", longitude: "+event.latLng.lng() ); 
    });
```

Comment: hey @laurence it works. it's good. but i want to use information windows. but, if i cant solve my problem, i'll use this code. thankyou so much :)

Comment: If you find this useful, please accept it as answer. Your welcome, happy coding. :)